# Dax Formula Measure: Calculate Median based on Invoice Total.. not each line item on the Invoice

Tags: excel, pivot-table, dax, powerpivot

I need to create a DAX formula for a measure in Excel that will calculate the median based on the Invoice total and not each line item on the invoice. For example

[Sample Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sCVhi.png)

If I calculate the median of this table for dollar values it will be 16.5. However I want to calculate the median at the grouped invoice level. If the formula is working properly the median $ value should be 56

*Please note: This table is just an example, I need to a DAX measure formula so I can create this calculation based on data in my data model.

Thank you!

Comment: Figured it out...

Comment: =MEDIANX(
SUMMARIZE(
Query1, 
Query1[Invoice Number], 
"Invoice Median", SUM(Query1[Dollars])), [Invoice Median])